# Network decrypt fails on ocassion, local decrypt OK

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl

I'm sending ciphers over the network and verifying that they can be decrypted before sending them out and they consistently come out of the test as functioning properly, yet when they get sent over the network, they no longer decrypt properly. This doesn't happen consistently. They get sent through and decrypt as they should more commonly than otherwise, however they are failing to decrypt often enough to create serious problems. I am guessing that some of the characters that are used in the cipher are not intended to travel over a network, so they are replaced at some point and thus the cipher returns from its journey in a broken state. It's just a guess, though. Anyone have any ideas? 
details:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'digest/sha1'

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
cipher.encrypt
key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("password")
iv = cipher.random_iv
```

The error messages I'm getting are mostly 'bad decrypt' but also 'iv length too short' and 'wrong final block length'. It seems to be related to time somehow because I seem to get either a streak of errors or a streak of clean decrypts more often than things being mixed so that kind of points toward a cipher character issue in my mind.

Comment: You're getting problems with decryption after the encrypted message with its open key was transfer through network?

Comment: @ted No, the key is static. It doesn't get transferred. The only things transferred are the cipher and the iv. Somehow, in the transfer the cipher seems to be getting broken because, before it gets transferred, it decrypts properly. I use literally the same code before and after the transfer for decryption.

Comment: That this is the character encoding is pretty likely. Base64 encode the output of your cipher to test and make sure your stream handling is up to scratch. Please post the code that is in error, not the code that is working correctly.

Comment: Surely you need to use the same IV at both ends, not a random IV?

Comment: @EJP I'm sending the IV with the cipher hence sometimes getting the 'IV length too short' line. Really makes me suspect character issues.

Comment: @owlstead I'm finding Base64 works perfectly until I go over a certain number of characters in my encrypted message and then it stops decrypting properly every time even if the next messages are only a few characters long so I'm not really sure what's up with this inconsistent behaviour but I'm going to be checking very carefully over my code. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @owlstead Seems to work perfectly. The Base64 encoding was segmenting for unknown reasons. It would appear that it is definitely a character issue. Is this something that could be caused by my system, or is it just a case of the ciphers being outputted not being compatible with conventional network protocols? For now, it seems best to me to continue to keep using Base64 for transport purposes.

Comment: Segmenting is probably due to the way streams are handled. Base64 is text too so match text encodings at both sides as well (keep to ASCII/UTF-8).

Comment: *`cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")`* - just [bike shedding](http://bikeshed.com/), but this is probably not enough to meet minimum security needs. You should probably be using AES/GCM to ensure confidentiality, integrity and authenticity. AES/CBC only provides confidentiality. With AES/GCM, the IV should be MAC'd as AAD. Also see a treatment on [Authenticated Encryption](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption).

Answer (score 1):

The encrypted text and the IV are strings are binary and thus contain characters that are unsafe to send over a network. You can unpack your binary string into hex and the send that over.

```
encrypted.unpack("H*).first
```

And on the other end:

```
encrypted_data = [hex_data].pack("H*")
```